# Snowflake CLI (Snowsql) - query tagging

Tags: sql, tagging, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

When a query is run from the snowsql shell, i get to see the generated query id on the UI. Later on if i have to search for the same in the history, i want to search the query id that i can define or someway to tag the query.

Is it possible to create my own query id or tag when i run the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create your own query id, but you can use the `QUERY_TAG` parameter, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#query-tag).

You can later use it when scanning the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY` table, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html), it has a `QUERY_TAG` column. You can also use a `Query Tag` filter in the `History` tab in the UI.

You can also use [LAST_QUERY_ID](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html) to obtain the Snowflake-generated `QUERY_ID` programmatically. And then you it to filter with that in the `QUERY_HISTORY` table, and also in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually supply this at the CLI:

if you have a SQL script (running_test.sql):

ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG = ;
/* followed by SQL */

Then you call snowsql cli in normal fashion:

snowsql -c "CONNECTION_NAME" -f "full_path_to_sql_file" > write_to_log_file

(Connection name is something you set in your config file)

or
snowsql "account_details + username + password" -f "full_path_to_sql_file" > write_to_log_file

Answer (score 1):

You can set a query tag for an account, user, or session. This is particularly helpful when tracking query behavior across many services.

*Note that setting `QUERY_TAG` will [act as a default and will be overridden](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-account.html#usage-notes) by more granular levels (account > user > session).*

```sql
/* 
  The following will provide a default query tag to all queries
  performed by an account (replace `MY_ACCOUNT` with your account name) 
*/
ALTER ACCOUNT MY_ACCOUNT SET
    QUERY_TAG = 'Data Warehouse'
;


/* ​
  The following will provide a default query tag to all queries
  ​performed by a user (replace `MY_USER` with your user name)
   
  NOTE: This is more granular than ACCOUNT and will override
    default QUERY_TAG
*/
ALTER USER MY_USER SET
    QUERY_TAG = 'Data Transformations'
;


/* ​
  The following will provide a query tag to all queries
  ​performed by this session.
  
  NOTE: This is more granular than USER and ACCOUNT and 
    will override  default QUERY_TAG
*/
ALTER SESSION SET
    QUERY_TAG = 'Doing this very specific task'
;
```